# What when user is not passing the complete json to a .NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST endpoint (ASP.NET Web API 2.2) which is expecting a defined json.

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetProcessStart([FromBody]MyDataWrapper myDataWrapper)
```

The MyDataWrapper json includes e.g. three parameters.

```
{
  "name": "Heinz",
  "color": "green",
  "hat": false
}
```

Two parameter *color* and *hat* are optional.
But when the user is passing that:

```
{
  "name": "Heinz"
}
```

myDataWrapper is null.

I tried:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SetProcessStart([FromBody]object myObject)
MyDataWrapper myDataWrapper = (MyDataWrapper)object;
```

but it does not work.

**How can I take on the short json and make it to my *MyDataWrapper* object?**

```
public class MyDataWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("color", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hat", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public bool Hat { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us the `MyDataWrapper` class.

Comment: Does passing all properties work as expected?

Comment: @DavidG I added the MyDataWrapper to the initial question.

Comment: `Required.AllowNull` means the property needs to exist but is allowed to be null. you probably want to use `Required.Default` or `Required.DisallowNull`.

Comment: @Fabio Yes, when the json is complete, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm) for `Required.AllowNull` (emphasis mine):

> The property ***must be defined*** in JSON but can be a null value.

This is why it is failing, because you have explicitly said the properties need to be provided. You should switch to either:

1. `Required.Default` - The property is not required. This is the default value meaning you could just completely remove the `Required` property altogether.
2. `Required.DisallowNull` - The property is not required but it cannot be a null value

Comment: you still need to pass it to controller either have value or null!

Comment: @Saif Using either of these options means you don't need to pass a value for those properties. I'm not sure what you are saying.